# Pyspark Column transformation using regex or any other transformations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can you please tell me how to convert the url column to output column rows in a Dataframe using pyspark.

Transformation rule :

1. replace https to abfss
2. replace "blob.core.windows.net" to dfs.core.windows.net
3. Extract text between 3rd '/' and last '/', + '@' + text between 2nd '/' and '.' + remaining string.

from pyspark.sql import Row

```
lst = [Row(url='https://inputfile.blob.core.windows.net/inputstorage/AvailabilityZones_1.csv', \
       output='abfss://inputstorage@inputfile.dfs.core.windows.net/AvailabilityZones_1.csv'), \
   Row(url='https://inputfile.blob.core.windows.net/inputstorage/AvailabilityZones_2.csv', \
       output='abfss://inputstorage@inputfile.dfs.core.windows.net/AvailabilityZones_2.csv'), \
   Row(url='https://inputfile.blob.core.windows.net/inputstorage/newfolder/AvailabilityZones_3.csv', \
       output='abfss://inputstorage/newfolder@inputfile.dfs.core.windows.net/AvailabilityZones_3.csv')]

df= spark.createDataFrame(lst)
```

expected dataframe as follows :
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGrN.jpg)

Comment: can you describe the transformation rule ?

Comment: why the 3rd line change from `AvailabilityZones_3` to `AvailabilityZones_2` ?

Comment: It was a mistake, please check the updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I am answering myself.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
def parseurl(url):
    fin_url=""
    url = url.replace('https://', 'abfss://')
    url = url.replace('blob.core.windows.net', 'dfs.core.windows.net')
    arr = url.split('/')
    sub_arr = []
    for pos in range(4,len(arr)-1):
        sub_arr.append(arr[pos])
    subFolder = ""
    if len(sub_arr)>0:
        subFolder = "/".join(str(x) for x in sub_arr)
    if subFolder != "":
        fin_url = url[:8] + arr[3] + '/' + subFolder + '@' + arr[2] + '/' + arr[-1]
    else:
        fin_url = url[:8] + arr[3] + '/' + subFolder + '@' + arr[2] + '/' + arr[-1]
    return fin_url
urlUDF = udf(lambda z: parseurl(z))
df.select(col("url"), \
    urlUDF(col("url")).alias("fin_url") ) \
   .show(truncate=False)
```